# Using O_CREAT O_WRONLY : How to get current position in the file and append data at the end?

Tags: c, file, sockets, flags, file-descriptor

I would like to read data from a socket into a **FILE**. If the **FILE** doesnt exist, create a file **ONLY ONCE** and any subsequent data from the client, find the current location of the **FILE POINTER** and append the data at the end.

Right now, a new file is being created everytime I run the code.

```
// Server is 'Ready' to read data from the socket :

// fd - declared as **static int**, to enable it bet'n the function calls


            fd = open("/home/regs_p/cprograms/tcp/RSA.c", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

              if (fd < 0) {

                printf("Some problem with the file!");

              }

            else {
            
                while ((b = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1)) > 0) {

                    if (fd > 0 ) {

                        fp = fdopen(fd, "a+");

                        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);

                    //  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);

                    }   

                    size = ftell(fp);
            
                }

            //  printf("Buffer = %s", buffer);

            }
```

Comment: Use `O_APPEND`. Then you don't need the file pointer at all.

Comment: Use `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "a");` rather than `open`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni And then lose the `fdopen()` ...

Comment: `fd = open("/home/regs_p/cprograms/tcp/RSA.c", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);` is incomplete.  When creating a file, you need to supply a third `mode_t` argument to [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), for example `fd = open("/home/regs_p/cprograms/tcp/RSA.c", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);`

Comment: @Andrew Henle - Yeah, right. I forgot about 'Umask' values. Learnt about 'Umask', in my Unix and Shell Scripting Programming Course about 12 years back. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

Using `O_APPEND` with `O_CREAT` will create the file only if it doesn't exist already. If it exists, the file will be opened and the file pointer will be positioned at the end by default.

Comment: Shouldnt it be O_WRONLY | O_APPEND?

Comment: @Ace.McCloud Yes, you are right. One of `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDONLY` or `O_RDWR` is mandatory with every `open()` call, so I simply didn't mention it. And the open should fail if the file doesn't exist and you haven't specified `O_CREAT`. So I guess it should be: `O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT`